# How to refetch query in a component located on another page, after some operation (any), but only when you go to this page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

There is a component "ComponentA" on the page /page1 that requests some data by graphql(QUERY) HOC. When requested, a cache is used.

```
// ComponentAContainer.js on /page1

import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import ComponentA from './ComponentA';
import { GET_DATA1_QUERY } from './queries';

export default graphql(GET_DATA1_QUERY)(ComponentA);
```

On another page /page2 there is a button, when clicking on which a mutation is performed, after which the command should be sent to execute the request to the component on the page /page1, but not immediately, but only when going to this page.

```
// ComponentBContainer.js on /page2

import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import ComponentB from './ComponentB';
import { MUTATION_DATA2 } from './queries';

const ComponentBConatiner = ({ mutationData2 }) => (
 <ComponentB onButtonClick={
   mutationData2({
     variables: {
       input: { foo: 'bar' }
     }
   }).then(() => {
     // ????????????
     // What do need to do to the ComponentAConatiner to
     // execute the query GET_DATA1_QUERY, but only when you go 
     // to the page /page1?
     // ????????????
   });
 } />
);

export default graphql(MUTATION_DATA2, { name: 'mutationData2' })(ComponentBConatiner);
```

The `refetchQueries` function is not appropriate, since the data is immediately requested. The `writeQuery` function is not appropriate, since the mutation does not return data that could be written to the `writeQuery`. The component in which the mutation occurs does not know anything about the component in which to refetch the data.